# How to operate multi query results on webflux?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I want to find all products on someone's favorite shops and found there is many nested code when coding in [reactive](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) way. Is this the correct way? Or if there are some better methods?

```
@Component
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ShopRepo shopRepo;
    @Autowired
    ProductRepo productRepo;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> products(ServerRequest req) {
        String userid = req.queryParam("userid");
        Flux<Shop> shops = shopRepo.favorite(uid);
        return shops
            .flapMap(s -> Mono.just(s.getId()))
            .collectList()
            .flapMap(list -> {
                String[] shopIds = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
                return ServerResponse.ok().body(productRepo.findByShops(shopIds), Product.class);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks okay for me

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks.

Comment: Edit your code and specify the types inside your lambdas so we can try to make it better. Your pipeline can be much much better than that.